# Integrate Quicksight with Cognito for access via Google login

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, amazon-quicksight

I have my enterprise Quicksight in place and with users using our company email to register an account (like john.doe@mycompany.com). We're using Gmail for business.

On the other hand we have developed another application backed by AWS Cognito user pool using Google as an identity provider, and since this is the same user base our intention was to use the same user pool for Quicksight access. In addition we will develop a Lambda that would synchronize Cognito user group association with Quicksight memberships if/when necessary.

I've followed the example described here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-amazon-quicksight-federated-single-sign-on-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/, but the problem is that even though I login as different users I get access to Quicksight via same IAM role. The Quicksight user associated with this role has a specific username starting with `CognitoQuickSight1-AuthRole-KX4Y16...` and email associated with the user I used to login the very first time.

Now I'm wondering if in this setup it's even possible to have different roles associated with different users so they can be differentiated on Quicksight side? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Link is dead. But information is still available over here:
https://noise.getoto.net/2017/10/06/use-amazon-quicksight-federated-single-sign-on-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign QuickSight user specific permission on Federated users.

Some AWS services allows to use the user identity in the resource base IAM policy.  For example [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) (to allow user to access only their 'directory' in a bucket) and [DynamoBD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_rows.html) (to allow user to only access item where their identity is the primary key).

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/security_iam_service-with-iam.html Quicksight does not support Resource based or Tag based policies.